# php - upload an image to a folder and resize it to an other folder

Tags: php

i have tow codes, one upload an image and another resize image, but i can't put this codes together to upload to a folder and resize it to another folder.

this is normal upload code :

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submitp"])) {
    $ppic="456.png";    
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['ppic']['name'];
    $ppicpath="_prf/u/".$ppic;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["ppic"]["tmp_name"],$ppicpath);

}
?><form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="position: relative;top: -20px;z-index: 1">
 <input type="file" name="ppic" class="button2"  >
 <input type="submit" name="submitp" value="submit">
 </form>
```

and this is resize code and move to another folder:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submitp"])) {
        $ppic = "123.png";
        $uploadO = 1;
        $path_thumbs = "_prf/u2/";
        //the new width of the resized image, in pixels.
        $img_thumb_width = 150; // 

        $extlimit = "yes";

        $limitedext = array(".gif",".jpg",".png",".jpeg",".bmp");

        //the image -> variables
        $file_type = $_FILES['ppic']['type'];
        $file_name = $_FILES['ppic']['name'];
        $file_size = $_FILES['ppic']['size'];
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['ppic']['tmp_name'];

       $ext = strrchr($file_name,'.');
       $ext = strtolower($ext);
       //uh-oh! the file extension is not allowed!
       if (($extlimit == "yes") && (!in_array($ext,$limitedext))) {
          echo "Wrong file extension. <br>--<a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]\">back</a>";
          exit();
       }

       $getExt = explode ('.', $file_name);
       $file_ext = $getExt[count($getExt)-1];

       $rand_name= "123.png";

        $ThumbWidth = $img_thumb_width;

       // CREATE THE THUMBNAIL //

    if($file_size){
          if($file_type == "image/pjpeg" || $file_type == "image/jpeg"){
               $new_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($file_tmp);
           }elseif($file_type == "image/x-png" || $file_type == "image/png"){
               $new_img = imagecreatefrompng($file_tmp);
           }elseif($file_type == "image/gif"){
               $new_img = imagecreatefromgif($file_tmp);
           }

        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file_tmp);

           $imgratio=$width/$height;
           if ($imgratio>1){
              $newwidth = $ThumbWidth;
              $newheight = $ThumbWidth/$imgratio;
           }else{
                 $newheight = $ThumbWidth;
                 $newwidth = $ThumbWidth*$imgratio;
           }

           $resized_img = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);

           imagecopyresized($resized_img, $new_img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

            ImageJpeg ($resized_img,"$path_thumbs/$rand_name");
           ImageDestroy ($resized_img);
           ImageDestroy ($new_img);

       }

      if ($uploadO == 0) {
          echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded."; 
            }elseif($uploadO == 1){   

    move_uploaded_file ("$path_thumbs/$rand_name", $file_tmp);
}
}
?><form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="position: relative;top: -20px;z-index: 1">
 <input type="file" name="ppic" class="button2"  >
 <input type="submit" name="submitp" value="submit">
 </form>
```

i can't put this codes together to upload to a folder and resize it to another folder.
thanks

Comment: What's wrong with the code? Does it crash? What goes wrong?

Comment: it's ok. but i want to put them together to upload image to a folder and resize it to another folder in one action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following demo ought to help solve the problem - some minor editing to the directories used will be required. There are comments throughout which should help - it is, after-all, not too different to the pieces of code you had. This was tested on all image types except gif but don't foresee issue with that.

```
<?php
    /*  Single file upload with resized thumbnail generation */


    # The name of the HTML file field
    $field='ppic';
    # The base directory for uploads
    $rootdir=realpath( __DIR__ . '/upload' );
    # The directory into which images will be saved
    $imagedir=sprintf( '%s/images', $rootdir );
    # The directory into which a new thumbnail will be generated
    $thumbsdir=sprintf( '%s/images/thumbs', $rootdir );
    # For PNG files, the default compression level ( normally 6 )
    $compression = 3;
    # Set to boolean again later to indicate success/failure
    $response = false;
    # max image width
    $imgwidth=150;
    # max file size
    $maxsize = pow( 1024, 2 ) * 2;  # 2Mb   
    # allowed file extensions
    $extensions=array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif','bmp');
    # allowed mimetypes
    $mimetypes=array('image/jpeg','image/png','image/gif','image/x-ms-bmp');            




    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_FILES[ $field ] ) ){
        try{

            # simple supporting functions
            function createdir( $path=null, $perm=0644 ) {
                if( !file_exists( $path ) ) {
                    mkdir( $path, $perm, true );
                    clearstatcache();
                }
            }
            function getratio( $w=false, $h=false ){
                return $w & $h ? $w / $h : false;
            }
            function getaspect( $w, $h ){
                if( $w==$h )return 's';
                elseif( $w > $h )return 'l';
                elseif( $h > $w )return 'p';
                else return 'e';
            }
            function getsize( $size ){
                 $units = array( 'B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB' );
                 $power = $size > 0 ? floor( log( $size, 1024 ) ) : 0;
                 return number_format( $size / pow( 1024, $power ), 2, '.', ',' ) . ' ' . $units[ $power ];
            }


            # ensure target directory structure exists
            createdir( $imagedir );
            createdir( $thumbsdir );


            $obj=(object)$_FILES[ $field ];
            $name=$obj->name;
            $tmp=$obj->tmp_name;
            $size=$obj->size;
            $type=$obj->type;
            $error=$obj->error;

            $ext=strtolower( pathinfo( $name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) );
            list( $width, $height, $type, $attr )=getimagesize( $tmp );
            $mime=image_type_to_mime_type( $type );

            # generate paths for images
            $targetfile = $imagedir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . basename( $name );
            $thumbnail = $thumbsdir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . basename( $name );


            # some basic tests
            if( !$error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK ) throw new Exception( sprintf('Upload failed with error code %d', $error ) );
            if( !in_array( $ext, $extensions ) ) throw new Exception( sprintf( 'bad file extension (%s)',$ext ) );
            if( !in_array( $mime, $mimetypes ) ) throw new Exception( sprintf( 'bad mime type (%s)', $mime) );
            if( $width < $imgwidth ) throw new Exception( sprintf('image is too small (%s)', $attr ) );
            if( $size > $maxsize ) throw new Exception( sprintf('image is too large ( %s )', getsize( $size ) ) );


            # save the uploaded image
            if( !is_uploaded_file( $tmp ) ) throw new Exception('file upload attack');
            $status = move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $targetfile );


            # if the file was saved OK, generate resized thumbnail
            if( $status & imagetypes() ){

                $ratio = getratio( $width, $height );
                $aspect= getaspect( $width, $height );

                switch( $aspect ){
                    case 's':
                        $thumbwidth = $thumbheight = $imgwidth;
                    break;
                    case 'l':
                        $thumbwidth = $imgwidth;
                        $thumbheight = $thumbwidth / $ratio;
                    break;
                    case 'p':
                        $thumbheight = $imgwidth;
                        $thumbwidth = $thumbheight * $ratio;
                    break;
                    case 'e':throw new Exception('bad foo');
                }

                # generate new image
                $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor( $thumbwidth, $thumbheight );

                # use appropriate methods for the type of file uploaded
                switch( $type ){
                    case IMG_JPG:
                        $source = @imagecreatefromjpeg( $targetfile );
                        if( $source ){
                            @imagecopyresized( $thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumbwidth, $thumbheight, $width, $height );
                            @imagejpeg( $thumb,$thumbnail );
                        }                   
                    break;

                    case IMG_PNG:
                    case 3:
                        $source = @imagecreatefrompng( $targetfile );
                        if( $source ){
                            @imagecopyresized( $thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumbwidth, $thumbheight, $width, $height );
                            @imagepng( $thumb, $thumbnail, $compression );
                        }
                    break;

                    case IMG_GIF:
                        $source = @imagecreatefromgif( $targetfile );
                        if( $source ){
                            @imagecopyresized( $thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumbwidth, $thumbheight, $width, $height );
                            @imagegif( $thumb, $thumbnail );
                        }
                    break;

                    case IMG_WBMP && PHP_VERSION_ID > 70200: # available for PHP v7.2+
                        $source = @imagecreatefrombmp( $targetfile );
                        if( $source ){
                            @imagecopyresized( $thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumbwidth, $thumbheight, $width, $height );
                            @imagebmp( $thumb, $thumbnail, true );
                        }
                    break;
                }


                # set the success/failure indicator
                $response = file_exists( $thumbnail ) && file_exists( $targetfile ) ? true : false;

                @imagedestroy( $thumb );
                @imagedestroy( $source );               
                @unlink( $tmp );

                clearstatcache();
                http_response_code( 200 );

            } else {
                throw new Exception( 'Failed to save the upoaded image' );
            }
        }catch( Exception $e ){
            /* something's gone wrong again */
            $html='
            <html>
                <head>
                    <meta charset="utf-8" />
                    <title>error</title>
                    <style>
                        body{display:flex;flex-direction:column;width:100%%;height:100vh;color:red;font-family:cursive;padding:0;margin:0}
                        h1,a{width:80%%;margin:auto;text-align:center;}
                    </style>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <h1>%s</h1>
                    <a href="javascript:location.href=location.href" target="_top">Reload</a>
                </body>
            </html>';
            $error=sprintf( 'Error: %s, line: %d', $e->getMessage(), $e->getLine() );
            http_response_code( 400 );
            exit( sprintf( $html, $error ) );
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>combined image upload & resize</title>
        <style>
            body{display:flex;margin:0;padding:0;height:100vh;font-family:calibri,verdana,arial;}
            html,html *{box-sizing:border-box;}
            form{display:flex;flex-direction:column;margin:auto;width:80%;height:80vh;align-items:center;padding:1rem;}
            form > fieldset{display:flex:flex:1;width:90%;min-width:90%;margin:1rem auto;flex-direction:row;border:1px dashed rgba(100,100,100,0.25);padding:2rem;align-items:center;justify-content:center;}
            input{padding:1rem;}
            [type='file']{border:1px solid rgba(100,100,100,0.25);padding:0.9rem}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <?php
                if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $response ) ){
                    /*
                        let user know the uploaded succeeded
                        ... or not

                        for this demo the upload folder is within the current
                        working directory thus image paths are relative to this
                        and not document root.
                    */
                    printf(
                        '<fieldset>
                            <h3>%s - File uploaded</h1>
                            <a href="%s" target="_blank">
                                <img src="%s" width=%d height=%d title="%s" alt="%s" />
                            </a>
                        </fieldset>',
                        $name,
                        ltrim( str_replace( array( __DIR__, '\\' ), array('','/'), $targetfile ),'/'),
                        ltrim( str_replace( array( __DIR__, '\\' ), array('','/'), $thumbnail ),'/'),
                        $thumbwidth,
                        $thumbheight,
                        $name,
                        $name
                    );
                }
            ?>
            <fieldset>
                <input type='file' name='ppic' />
                <input type='submit' />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```